# Keeping one country from a sheet and deleting the rest

Tags: excel, vba

Every quarter I receive an Excel file with lots of countries and several sheets with different variables being measured for each country company. What I'm supposed to do with it is to create an Excel file for every country. What I'm doing until now is just deleting it manually, which takes a lot of time.

I uploaded a simple example file. First sheet is the original output structure, usually coming with 20-25 sheets measuring different variables from several companies and countries. In the example, for the sake of simplicity, I just put two countries: the UK and France. Second sheet is what I need to produce, keeping only the UK and deleting France. Of course, I also have to do one file with only France.

I hope I've made myself clear so you can help me with this.

[Example file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dwiqq971lkmyx8c/example.xlsm?dl=0)

Comment: If you're going to post an example file it's usually best (unless you need to share code) to make it an xlsx and not xlsm.  People are quite nervous about downloading macro-enabled files, or at least they should be.

Comment: Having said that, I did download it, and it's not clear whether it matches your description - you say there are 20-25 sheets in the source file - did you copy-paste those onto a single sheet for the example "original output", or are there more sheets which look exactly like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used a parameter to pass into a filter for this sub.

```
Sub there_can_be_only_one(sCOUNTRY As String)
    With Sheets("Original_output").Columns(4)
        With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2).Offset(0, -2)
            With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
                'Debug.Print .Address(0, 0)
                .FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
            End With
        End With
    End With
    With Sheets("Original_output").Columns(2)
        With .Cells(6, 1).Resize(.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1)
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>" & sCOUNTRY, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>"
            With .Offset(1, 0)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
                .AutoFilter
            End With
        End With
    End With
    With Sheets("Original_output").Columns(3)
        With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
            .Offset(0, -1).ClearContents
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

I'm not sure how you want to handle the borders at the bottom of some of the data islands as your example simply left them out. If  they are required, you should write some code to reinstate them after the row deletion.

Execute the sub by calling it like,

```
Call there_can_be_only_one("UK")
 ... or,
there_can_be_only_one "UK"
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer by a Reddit user:

```
Sub Cleaner()
Dim savedel As Boolean
Dim cellcounter As Integer
Dim country As String

country = InputBox("Enter Country to Save")
If country = "" Then Exit Sub

cellcounter = 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Do Until cellcounter > Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    'Ignore deletion of any spacer rows
    If IsEmpty(Range("D" & cellcounter)) = True And IsEmpty(Range("E" & cellcounter)) = True Then
        savedel = 1

        'Ignore heading rows
        ElseIf Len(Range("F" & cellcounter)) > 0 And IsNumeric(Left(Range("F" & cellcounter), 1)) = False Then
            savedel = 1

        'Ignore deletion of the country sought
        ElseIf Range("B" & cellcounter).Value = country Then
            savedel = 1

        'Flag non-country for deletion
        ElseIf Range("B" & cellcounter).Value <> country And IsEmpty(Range("B" & cellcounter).Value) = False Then
            savedel = 0
    End If

    'If flagged, delete row
    If savedel = 0 Then
        Rows(cellcounter).Delete
        cellcounter = cellcounter - 1
    End If

cellcounter = cellcounter + 1

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```